# Split array into chunks in C/C++

Tags: c++, arrays, windows, split

I am looking for a way to split an array into multiple arrays in C/C++, with standard Win32 and C/C++ functions.

Here's an example, how I read a file into the array.

```
using namespace std;

LPSTR File_To_Read = "FILE.exe"; 
DWORD File_To_Read_Size = NULL;
DWORD inputSize = NULL;
PBYTE inputData = NULL;

ifstream input(File_To_Read, ifstream::binary | ifstream::ate);
File_To_Read_Size = static_cast<DWORD>(input.tellg());
input.seekg(input.beg);

inputData = new BYTE[File_To_Read_Size];
input.read(reinterpret_cast<char*>(inputData), File_To_Read_Size);
input.close();
```

Now I want to split the inputData like this.

```
DWORD inputSize_part1;
DWORD inputSize_part2;
DWORD inputSize_part3;

PBYTE inputData_part1;
PBYTE inputData_part2;
PBYTE inputData_part3;
```

So in the later I can also put them back together.

How should I proceed? I would show an example code what I have tried, but my code would not make not much sense for you experts.

Edit:
@IKH Chunk sizes should be around the same size. So if inputData is 33kb, then inputData_part1(and inputSize_part1) should be 11kb, inputData_part2(and inputSize_part2) should be 11kb, and so on. So in the end there would be 3x 11kb arrays and DWORDS for their sizes.

Comment: `I would show an example code what I have tried, but my code would not make not much sense for you experts.` Oh, stop it, you :$
Show us the code anyway.

Comment: chunks? what chunks? you don't specify either the size of chunk or the number of chunk.

Comment: @nouney Actually I don't have it anymore. I splitted the size in 3, then looped 3 times and tried reading always 1/3 of the array into split1, split2, split3 + their sizes but at the moment I have no idea where I should begin with. Edit: IKH edited the post.

Comment: Read into a single (dynamic) array, then treat that array as 3 different arrays: `int *arr1 = fullarray; int *arr2 = fullarray + chunksize; int *arr3 = fullarray + 2 * chunksize;`

Comment: Please pick *one* language. It seems you've chosen C++. C is not the same.

Comment: Either one. The above code is indeed C++ but it does not matter if someone shows an example in C. I tried just five minutes ago what _pmg_ said, but I couldn't make it work. :S

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
DWORD inputSize_part1 = inputSize / 3;
DWORD inputSize_part2 = inputSize / 3;
DWORD inputSize_part3 = inputSize - inputSize_part1 - inputSize_part2;

PBYTE inputData_part1 = inputData;
PBYTE inputData_part2 = inputData + inputSize_part1;
PBYTE inputData_part3 = inputData + inputSize_part1 + inputSize_part2;
```

Now you have three pointers and three sizes for the three chunks: the first two are a third or slightly less, and the third chunk may be slightly larger if the original was not evenly divisible.  You'll need to `delete[] inputData` when you're doing using all of the chunks.

Answer (score 0):

The actual chunk size shouldn't matter. Following up on @pmg's comment, after the line `input.read(reinterpret_cast<char*>(inputData), File_To_Read_Size);`, you have a single array to store the data. The size of the shortest array will always be `File_To_Read_Size / 3` because that is the number of arrays you are splitting it into. For access, the index used would be slightly augmented by the index of the chosen array, like so:

```
//assume array_index is the number of the array you are accessing (1,2, or 3)
//and position is the location you are trying to access in that array
BYTE result = inputData[position + (array_index - 1)];
```

Using this, all you need to know is what `File_To_Read_Size % 3` is. If `File_To_Read_Size % 3 == 1`, then the first array contains the last BYTE. Else if `File_To_Read_Size % 3 == 2`, then the second array contains the last BYTE. Otherwise, all the arrays are the same size. Each of the first two `if`s would thus be a check for whether the index is valid.